# Why is Luke so indecisive in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, character-motivation

I'm not talking about why he is so pessimistic and miserable, but why he constantly considers changing his mind throughout the film in the briefest of moments before reverting back to how he originally felt. Did Rian Johnson have a reason for this? The end result still has him

> fulfilling his wish of dying on the island so why tease the audience repeatedly?

The most notable example that struck me is when he

> goes to burn down the tree and the ancient Jedi texts. He stops suddenly, changes his mind, and actively tries to get in to save the texts after Yoda brings the lightning down upon the tree.

What was the reason for Luke's indecision throughout the film, has Rian Johnson commented on this?

Comment: He's devoted his whole life to the jedi, he is still one. Just because he thinks they should end doesn't mean he has the heart to go through with it.

Comment: Even in the original trilogy (at least ANH and ESB) Luke was pretty whiney and indecisive.  In ROTJ he seemed to get his act together, but maybe living alone on an isolated planet for however many years led him to revert to his old ways.  (I'm sure the way things ended with Kylo and his Jedi School didn't exactly help his self-confidence, either.)

Comment: Luke is traumatized. The Empire killed his family, he was pushed into fighting a war, he learned he was descended from a crazy mass murderer, and he had to deal with the need to kill his newly found father to save everyone else. Plus the incest thing. No matter how heroic and brave we may want to call him, he's been severely hurt by those events. Now he's the last surviving Jedi, with a cosmic weight on his shoulders. Failing to properly train his first students was just the last straw. Of course he second-guesses himself at every step: the galaxy is at stake and he didn't have full mentoring.

Comment: There are three good comments that could be backed up from the movies and presented as good answers, so how can this question be primarily opinion-based?